# Change operator on two numbers according to a loop or user input - Python

Tags: python, math, operators, calculator

Is there a way to change the arithmetic operator that is used on two integers, depending on a variable? For example, if I wanted to code a calculator, where instead of creating a new function for each operator, i could create one function; something like:

```
ops = {0 : +, 1 : -, 2 : *, 3 : /}
for i in range(4):
    print(12ops[i]4)
```

or:

```
ops = {0 : +, 1 : -, 2 : *, 3 : /}
i = int(input("What operator?"))
print(12ops[i]4)
```

**Example Output:**

```
16
8
48
3
What operator? 2
8
>>>
```

However, this obviously wouldn't work, as this is not the correct way (if there is one) to do this, and would just return Syntax Error in the dictionary.
Using this, I would create something such as a simple calculator.
I feel that this is a question that i, and probable many others have asked themselves if it is possible in python, and it would be very useful for other programming projects in the future.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how you can do that.

```
ops = {0 : "+", 1 : "-", 2 : "*", 3 : "/"}
for i in range(4):
    print(eval("12"+ops[i]+"4"))
i = int(input("What operator?"))
print(eval("12"+ops[i]+"4"))
```

Comment: That does indeed work, and the way you used `eval()` is safe, but using `eval()` in general is deprecated since it can be unsafe.

Comment: you are right @RoryDaulton it's better not to use `eval()` but for this requirement, I found it okay. but again I don't recommend anyone to use `eval()`

Comment: I didn't even know `eval ()` existed, but would you say the first answer is better/more useful than this one?

Comment: Yes, if you're just operating on basic operations, that's the best answer. personally, I would recommend using operation if that's the only case. but if you want to override operation or you want to add more complex operations I don't think operation will work in that case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use functions, they are first class citizens in Python, so you can put them pretty much anywhere:

```
import operator
ops = {0: operator.add, 1: operator.sub, 2: operator.mul, 3: operator.div}

for i in range(4):
    print(ops[i](12, 4))
```

Outputs:

```
16
8
48
3
```